# Get values using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the "data-val" from my soup, but they all come in a huge list and not formatted in different lists/columns as show in the website.

I know the headers are here:

```
<th class="num record drop-3" data-tsorter="data-val">
    <span class="long-points">
     proj. pts.
    </span>
    <span class="short-points">
     pts.
    </span>
   </th>
   <th class="pct" data-tsorter="data-val">
    <span class="full-relegated">
     relegated
    </span>
    <span class="small-relegated">
     rel.
    </span>
   </th>
   <th class="pct" data-tsorter="data-val">
    <span class="full-champ">
     qualify for UCL
    </span>
    <span class="small-champ">
     make UCL
    </span>
   </th>
   <th class="pct sorted" data-tsorter="data-val">
    <span class="drop-1">
     win Premier League
    </span>
    <span class="small-league">
     win league
    </span>
   </th>
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
url = 'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/premier-league/'
r = requests.get(url = url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"forecast-table"})
#print(table.prettify())
for i in table.find_all("td", {"class":"pct"}):
     print(i)
```

So ideally I'd like 4 lists, with the class names and then the matching values

Comment: I'm not really able to figure out what particular columns you're trying to read. When I open the URL in a browser, each team shows about 11 columns; which ones are you looking for?

Comment: The last 4 ("pts", "relegated", "qualify for ucl" and "win premier league"). I believe the class names in the html are: "long-points", "full-relegated", "full_champ" and "drop-1". But not really sure, I'm quite newbie to BS4. Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure what specific cols you want but this gets all the ones with a `data-val` in the tag's attributes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/soccer-predictions/premier-league/'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "forecast-table"})

team_rows = table.find_all("tr", {"class": "team-row"})

for team in team_rows:
    print("Team name: {}".format(team['data-str']))

    team_data = team.find_all("td")

    for data in team_data:
        if hasattr(data, 'attrs') and 'data-val' in data.attrs:
            print("\t{}".format(data.attrs['data-val']))
    print("\n")
```

If I do understand your question correctly, you're looking for the last couple of values, which are fairly untagged in the html source. When that's the case, you can try simply looking for `tag[6]`, although it's of course not very robust - but this *is* html parsing, so "not very robust" is par for the course imho.

what I'm doing here is finding all the team rows (which is easy thanks to the class name), and then simply looping through all the `td` tags that are in the team rows' `tr`.